# Apache reverse proxy to localhost doesn't work

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy, kibana

I want to use the open source ELK stack. Kibana has no security at all in the free version. My Idea is, that I put Kibana behind an Apache reverse proxy using Apache's basic authentication, but somehow the reverse proxy doesn't work.

I have the only one site enabled, with the following content:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName          kibana2.softxs.ch
    ProxyPreserveHost   On
    ProxyRequests       Off
    ProxyPass           / http://127.0.0.1:5601/ retry=0
    ProxyPassReverse    / http://127.0.0.1/
</VirtualHost>
```

Kibana is listening on port 5601:

```
$ netstat -lnp | grep 5601
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:5601          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      16465/node
```

Apache is listening on port 80:

```
netstat -lnp | grep 80
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN      21721/apache2
```

However if I'm using http://kibana2.softxs.ch, I get the Apache2 Ubuntu Default Page. I don't understand it, because there is no other file in `site_enabled`. There is no error message in apache log.

`apachectl -S` says:

```
VirtualHost configuration:                                                                          
ServerRoot: "/etc/apache2"                                                                          
Main DocumentRoot: "/var/www/html"                                                                  
Main ErrorLog: "/var/log/apache2/error.log"                                                         
Mutex ssl-stapling: using_defaults                                                                  
Mutex proxy: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-cache: using_defaults
Mutex default: dir="/var/lock/apache2" mechanism=fcntl 
Mutex watchdog-callback: using_defaults
Mutex ssl-stapling-refresh: using_defaults
PidFile: "/var/run/apache2/apache2.pid"
Define: DUMP_VHOSTS
Define: DUMP_RUN_CFG
User: name="www-data" id=33
Group: name="www-data" id=33
```

"/var/www/html" could come only from apache compile time. It is not defined anywhere, better said only in non-enabled virtual host:

```
/etc/apache2# grep -r '/var/www/html'
sites-available/000-default.conf:       DocumentRoot /var/www/html
sites-available/default-ssl.conf:               DocumentRoot /var/www/html
```

I see only simple entries in `other_vhosts_access.log` even if `LogLevel debug proxy:trace5` is added to the VirtualHost config:

```
zg-3.softxs.ch:80 188.143.71.45 - - [03/May/2019:17:26:31 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 3525 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"
zg-3.softxs.ch:80 188.143.71.45 - - [03/May/2019:17:26:31 +0200] "GET /icons/ubuntu-logo.png HTTP/1.1" 304 180 "http://kibana2.softxs.ch/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/72.0.3626.119 Safari/537.36"
```

Comment: Try to add `LogLevel debug proxy:trace5` into VirtualHost and see what is written to logs when you open a page. If issue is not clear from log, please post it here. This will help to debug.

Comment: BTW, X-Pack was [opensourced](https://www.elastic.co/products/x-pack/open) in elasticseach version 6.3. So you might consider using native features of kibana now.

Comment: What does `apachectl -S` say?

Comment: @Lacek I added the output to the question.

Comment: @Vladimir I added the log output above to the question, nothing special.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was quite trivial. In `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf` the following lines includes the virtual host configuration:

```
IncludeOptional sites-enabled/*.conf
```

But my virtual host config hasn't `.conf` extension. I added it and it works perfectly.